# Maximum file descriptors used by visual code

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, file-descriptor

I am trying to fix a bug in an ubuntu 20.04 program where it silently crashes once the maximum opened file descriptors (1024) is exceeded. I noticed that when running the program with visual code, ubuntu allows that number to be exceeded. This happens even if I run the program from visual code's terminal.

My question is how does visual code bypass this limitation, as I am looking to replicate that in my own app.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your question has two parts: A) max opened file descriptors in Ubuntu, and B) how vs code executes your program 'bypassing' said limit. Though you *did not* mention your Ubuntu *version* nor provide a sample of the error viz your program, I have proposed a general solution:

For question A: This question is already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049058/how-to-increase-max-open-files-limit-on-ubuntu-18-04#1049062.

For question B: By default, VS Code runs in hidden directory in your home directory, `~/.vscode`. To find out the bypass (I am not sure that is what is going on here though), open terminal, and do the following:

```bash
$ cd
$ ls -Flha
```

After locating the `.vscode` directory, inspect the files and directories with `ls` command and any useful options/flags such as `-R` (to list recursively). You can use pipes and filters technique including `wc` with appropriate options for files and/or sub-directories (which may have been hidden, except we used -a flag to listen the hidden ones earlier), and output your results to view as a plaintext file. Try repeating until you find the culprit.

I recommend this quick [guide](https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/) for a refresher if you need help working with CLI.

Comment: Sorry for missing info, I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and the error I got in the terminal after crash was: too many open files. I am interested in question B as you named it, I will also edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @EmilBîc thank you for providing the version for Ubuntu. I am continuing to research the cause. So far, I suspect that the behavior of vs code, its current configuration, or any extensions (viewable in the hidden `~/.vscode` directory) may allow this limit bypass. Certain extensions significantly change how the program would actually behave. Finally, it could be an issue with where `tmp` and `usr` data are stored re your project. You may want to inspect with `sudo` those & use wildcard expressions for anything related to your project. You may find a related config. Cheers!

Comment: I finally decided to use `setrlimit` in my code. Basically I set the soft limit to the value of the hard limit of max open files for my process. After changing my system's hard limit I noticed that this is also what vs code does, it adapts it's process limits to that value. But I don't think they are using `setrlimit` because I couldn't find anything in their repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the maximum file descriptors  limit by `ulimit`.

Type `ulimit -n` for display you current file descriptors limit

For change limit type `ulimit -n NEED_LIMIT` where NEED_LIMIT - number of maximum file descriptors

e.g. `ulimit -n 4096`

Comment: I am aware that I can change the limit of my sistem, but I am more interested in a way in which my program can bypass that by itself, as Visual Studio Code seems to do.